# Does Ubuntu Touch support DisplayLink?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, displaylink

The superbook is a laptop shell fit Android phones that uses DisplayLink over the phone's USB port. The owners say that the DL video also works with Windows Phones because they support DL.

Does Ubuntu Touch support DL or will it on future releases?

Comment: What superbook are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Touch currently does not support display link.
While there is a driver voor de x86 architecture there is no binary build for arm.
I have filed a suggestion to them on [their uservoice](https://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/37143457-add-support-for-ubuntu-touch).
As of August 2019 no response

Comment: July 2021 still no response

Comment: june 2022 still no response

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu there is driver for DL, you need to have compatible hardware.